# What does this mean in 3 from hell?

Tags: dialogue, 3-from-hell

In the movie ***3 from Hell***, when Captain Spaulding is interviewed before his execution, he says:

> **Captain Spaulding:** What's the difference between a dead squirrel lying
>   in the road and a dead clown lying in the road?
>
> **Travis O'Rourke:** I don't understand the question.
>
> **Captain Spaulding:** Do I stutter?
>
> **Travis O'Rourke:** I don't know.
>
> **Captain Spaulding:** There are skid marks in front of the squirrel.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a play on the fact that no-one likes clowns, but everybody loves squirrels.

If you see a squirrel in the road, you will brake to try avoid hitting it.

if you see a clown… you may actually even speed up a bit, to be sure to hit it.